# Web scrapping con Bs4 -> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup, web-scrapping

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto de web scraping con BeautifulSoup y Requests en Django, extrayendo datos de páginas web que me mostrarán ciertos productos, su imagen, precio, etc. Al momento que quiero extraer una imagen tengo un error:
**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.**

Estoy realizando el manejo de errores con try-except-finally de manera que aunque no logré extraer la ruta de la imagen, pueda seguir haciendo scrapping de los otros datos y esto me funciona bien. Pero, como ya mencioné, no me muestra las imágenes y me sale el error de Nonetype, entiendo que este error me indica algo como que la etiqueta a la que estoy llamando no contiene nada (corríjanme si me equivoco), pero según el panel de inspeccionar, si es la etiqueta que tiene la ruta de la imagen. Entonces, ¿en qué me estoy equivocando al llamar a la etiqueta img? ¿podría llamar al div que contiene la img dentro para que se pueda extraer la ruta de la imagen?

El código en views.py

```
try:
  product.find('img', attrs={'class':'no-js lazyautosizes'})['srcset']
except:
  print(error)
finally:
  product.find('p').text
  product.find('small', attrs= {'aria-hidden':'true'}).text
```

Les agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Comment: Si esa es la línea que te muestra el error lo más probable es que `product.find()` este retornando `None` y no puedes hacer None['src']. Has probado colocar un `try except` para capturar el error ?

Comment: Me sirvió el manejo de errores con try-except, gracias. Pero sigo sin poder mostrar las imágenes ¿qué sería lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Seria de gran ayuda ver como estas codificando el condicional para validar si tienen o no imagen!, Edita la pregunta y agrega el código

Comment: Ya no estoy usando la condicional porque el try-except cumple lo que quería hacer. De todas maneras edité la pregunta, espero haberme podido explicar mejor. Gracias.